# Flywheel being replaced

Tags: crankshaft

I have a 2016 Mercedes GLE350, they replaced the crankshaft sensor, car still not running good, now they are replacing the flywheel. This is not normal on a 2016 car with low milage. the car is still under warranty, what should I be on the look out as far as the future on this car????Not Happy

Comment: Hmm, "not normal".. well things can go wrong and that happens... It may be that the car has a lot of stop / starts and if the flywheel was sub-standard the problem has surfaced earlier than it might have done if it only did long highway journeys.

Comment: It is not normal for a flywheel to be consumed at this point, but from time to time it happens that otherwise solid parts break in a short time. I would be glad to have it replaced free of charge, as the flywheel (DMF I assume) is perishable and expensive.